# What SEO software do you use to analyze your websites?

Tags: seo

I'm looking for a tool that would help you manage the SEO work like improving and tracking things like keywords, description, pages links, analyze concurrent websites.

I'm not looking for black SEO software that do mass link submission and I'm aware the a significant part of the work does not require a specialized software for that - a spreadsheet can usually help - still a spreadsheet doesn't check for changes.

There are quite a few software on the web but I'm not sure about their cost/benefit ratio and is *almost impossible to find real reviews or comparisons between them*. They fully used they SEO knowledge to bring their own reviews on the search engines.

If you **had a good experience** with one of them please recommend it here.

**Update #1**

- [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/)
- [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)
- [Yahoo Sites Explorer](https://siteexplorer.search.yahoo.com/mysites)

I'm looking for features that are **missing** from the the ones listed above like:

- **detect and analyze competitor websites**
- **track links to you and observe if you loose or gain new ones**
- **track positioning overtime**

PS. I know Microsoft had a SEO solution but this one is out of question because it is only for IIS.

Comment: You are not entirely correct about Microsoft's SEO beign IIS only - it requires IIS for installation (still a mystery to me why that is the case), but will perform analysis for any server/OS (I use it all the time against Apache-hosted sites)

Comment: @Jeff - shouldn't you declare that SEO is banned from all stack-exchange sites - this question was closed on all of them because it was'nt considered appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

[Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics) and [Google Webmaster](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en) tools do pretty much everything I need. Good and free.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot accept this as an answer. I was my mistake that I did not specified that I'm looking for more than the base tools.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but have you looked at [Mint](http://haveamint.com/)?